# Mobile App to Work Along side a Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mobile

Ive made a Windows Form Application and all is working fine on that.
but what im trying to do is make it so people have a mobile App(that ill end up making) that will allow them to be away from the PC and push a button on the mobile app that will send someform or command to the Winform Application and get it to trigger a button click event.

E.G

Winform is open on PC has a button on it that will play or pause music.

I go get a drink downstairs and i want to pause the music from the mobile app.

Push the button on the mobile app and it connects to the Winform application and triggers the event for the pause button.

If anyone can help me out with this or put me in the right direction to do somthing like this that would be great. thank you.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you just described is that you need to build a mobile application.

There are several tools that allow you to move your application to web. I used to work with these guys, they were called Artinsoft at the time but they are now called Mobilize.net, and they have a tool for making this conversion: www.mobilize.net/press/topic/convert-windows-to-web

However in your cases it seems like what you are trying to build is a remote control, in this case you need to either expose an endpoint for a mobile app to connect to or create a centralized server that both the remote and Winforms connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a TCP/IP connection. I don't know anything about mobile development, so I'll just focus on .NET and the concepts should carry-over.

System.Net.Sockets contains TCP classes for opening connections to hosts/clients. I'd recommend that the desktop-app acts as the host while the mobile-app is the client.

There are plenty of online articles on the subject, so take one and explore it's code until you understand it. Then, prototype your task on a single desktop machine using two-different .NET programs, one for the host (mimics the desktop program in the final project) and the other as the client (mimics the mobile-app in the final project). Then, learn the mobile API for networking and mimic what you did in the client-test program on-to the mobile platform project.